# Can anyone figure out the sign of the following definite integral?

Tags: divergent-integrals

$$
\int_0^1 B^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha + \alpha x}} x^{k - 1} \left(\frac{\alpha \log{\left(B \right)}}{(\alpha-k-1)^2} +\frac{1}{k} +   \log{\left(x \right)}  \right)  dx,
$$
where $B\geq 2$, $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $k\geq 1$.

All my numerical experiments prove that this is a negative number, but I don't know how to prove it. Is there any theory for similar integrals?

Comment: for small $\alpha$ this evaluates to $$-\frac{\alpha^2 B (k^2+k-1) (2+\ln B) \ln B}{k (k+1)^3 (k+2)^2}+{\cal O}(\alpha^3),$$ which is indeed negative for $k\geq 1$, $B\geq 2$, so it would be sufficient to prove that it's a decreasing function of $\alpha$.

Comment: Follow-up question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457264/why-is-the-sign-of-the-integration-negative