# Why is the sign of the integration negative?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, asymptotics

Let
\begin{aligned}
I=\int_0^1 B^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha + \alpha x}} x^{k - 1} \left(\frac{\alpha \log{\left(B \right)}}{(\alpha-k-1)^2} +\frac{1}{k} +   \log{\left(x \right)}  \right)  dx,
\end{aligned}
where $B\geq 2, \alpha \in (0,1), k\geq 1$. Determine the sign of $I$.

[Carlo Beenakker](https://mathoverflow.net/users/11260/carlo-beenakker) shows that for small  it evaluates to

\begin{aligned}
I= -\frac{\alpha^2 B\left(k^2+k-1\right)(2+\ln B) \ln B}{k(k+1)^3(k+2)^2}+\mathrm{O}\left(\alpha^3\right),
\end{aligned}

I have tried numerical experiments and I find that they are not necessarily close to each other especially when $B$ is very large. Still, this is a good solution if we can prove that the asymptotic estimate is an upper bound for the real integration.

The problem in question actually originates from a control system. I have a function $T_k$ which can be expressed as:

\begin{equation}
T_k = k \int_{0}^1  x^{k-1} B^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha + \alpha x}} \, dx.
\end{equation}

My objective is to find the optimal value of $k$ that minimizes the entire system function.

However, evaluating the integral introduces considerable complexity, especially when analyzing the optimal point. As a result, I demonstrated that $ B^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha/(k+1)}}$ serves as a lower bound for this function. Subsequently, I established a series of theorems linking this lower bound to the actual integral.

My goal was to determine the ratio given by:

\begin{equation}
u_k = k \int_{0}^1  x^{k-1} B^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha + \alpha x}-\frac{1}{1-\alpha/(k+1)}} \, dx.
\end{equation}

This ratio exhibits monotonically decreasing behavior with respect to $k$. I differentiated this parameterized integral, transforming the problem into proving that its derivative is negative, implying that $I$ is less than 0.

I am sorry for bringing up this question again. When I posted it, I did not register, and I lost my right to even comment on the old question when I closed the question window.

Comment: Thanks https://mathoverflow.net/users/11260/carlo-beenakker for contributing to this question.

Comment: It may help if you disclose how this problem arises, in as much detail as possible.

Comment: Thanks for helping with the question, I have updated the description.

Comment: I've shared the link to this new question within the previous post. I hope this doesn't raise any concerns.